# Why is the IConfiguration object null after injecting it to DbContext? [ASP.NET Core 3.1]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext, appsettings

Before posting this question I have gone through multiple posts that are similar. My question focuses on "why is it happening despite applying the common and possibly right solution?".

I am developing a .NET Core 3.1 web app. I have a DbContext named 'SkipQContext'. I am trying to access the connection string from `appsettings.json` in the `SkipQContext` file using `Configuration` object.

For that, I have injected `IConfiguration` as a service to the `SkipQContext` constructor.

**Constructor:**

```
private readonly string ConnectionString;

public SkipQContext()
{ 
}

public SkipQContext(DbContextOptions<SkipQContext> options, IConfiguration configuration)
    : base(options)
{
    ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

I have also registered in **ConfigureServices** method of `Startup` class.

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

Now when I instantiate `SkipQContext` in one of my repository classes, the default constructor of `SkipQContext` is called. When I try to fetch data using it, I get the "IConfiguration object is null."

I applied breakpoints in `ConfigureServices` method and can see that the `IConfiguration` object has the connection string value.

My first question is, why is it null in `SkipQContext` when I am registering it in `ConfigureServices` and also injecting it in `SkipQContext` constructor? Multiple answers online state this as the right method.

Also, I am thinking, I might not be instantiating the `SkipQContext` rightly. As my statement :

```
SkipQContext db = new SkipQContext();
```

hits the default constructor of `SkipQContext` which is empty and not the overloaded constructor where `IConfiguration` is injected.

P.S. If the last question is dumb. I am still a bit unclear about how dependency injection works in .NET Core.

Comment: Did you follow the steps explained in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Had to remove the default constructor from `SkipQContext` and an object instantiation that used it elsewhere in the project. Registered the context as a service in `Startup.cs` and removed the `OnConfiguring` method from `SkipQContext`. Thanks to @poke for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I am thinking, I might not be instantiating the `SkipQContext` rightly. As my statement:
>
> ```
> SkipQContext db = new SkipQContext();
> ```
>
> hits the default constructor of `SkipQContext` which is empty and not the overloaded constructor where `IConfiguration` is injected.

You are right, this is not how dependency injection is supposed to work. Whenever you do `new Something`, then you are *explicitly* going around dependency injection. The main point about dependency injection is that a component that has a dependency (e.g. a database context) does not need to create that dependency itself, or even *know* how to create that dependency itself.

When you call `new SkipQContext()`, you *are* explicitly creating that depenndency, so you are *tightly* coupled to that `SkipQContext` and whatever that context needs in order to work properly (in this case, it needs `DbContextOptions` and `IConfiguration`). What you want instead is components to be [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) to their dependencies. So you just declare what dependencies you *need* and require that someone or something else fulfills these dependencies for you. And that’s exactly where dependency injection comes in:

With dependency injection, you have a “dependency injection container” which takes care of creating all the dependencies that you or some component may require. You configure the container in a central location, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, and then you are able to simply declare what dependencies you need via a service’s constructor. But in order for the container to provide these dependencies to that service, the service will have to be created *by* the container itself.

So what you will see is that you will basically have to consume everything through dependency injection. But this also makes it easy to realize when you are not using dependency injection: Whenever you write `new Something`, then that something won’t be created by the container and as such won’t have its dependencies automatically fulfilled. Depending on what that something is that might be what you want, or maybe not (e.g. creating a `List<string>` or a DTO object is something you want to do directly, creating a service or something that has other dependencies likely isn’t).

Coming back to your problem, in order to have the DI container take care of the dependencies in the constructor of `SkipQContext`, you will have to let the DI container create that context for you. So you cannot create it with `new` but instead you will have to *depend* on it by adding it to the constructor of whatever component you need it in.

E.g. if you have a controller, just add it as a dependency there:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SkipQContext _db;

    public HomeController(SkipQContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var items = await _db.Items.ToListAsync();
        return View(new IndexViewModel
        {
            Items = items,
        });
    }
}
```

One final note regarding your database context: If you register the database context *correctly* with the DI container, then it will already be configured using the `DbContextOptions` that gets passed to the constructor. These options will also include the connection string the context needs to open the database connection. So you do not need to pass the `IConfiguration` manually or extract the connection string there. It will be automatically done for you by EF Core.

A proper context setup could look like this (in `ConfigureServices`):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SkipQContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the explanation. I still have confusion. What do I need to write in OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) function that is inside SkipQContext class? The problem is that the connection string is being accessed and set there. I can do the context setup inside ConfigureServices as you say, but what about optionsBuilder inside OnConfiguring of SkipQContext? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Junaid You can remove the `OnConfiguring` completely because the default behavior is to use the configuration from the `DbContextOptions` if that constructor is used.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, after removing the OnConfiguring 
 completely. I get the following exception: InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: @Junaid Did you register your database context correctly with the service collection? I.e. that `services.AddDbContext<>` call that I showed at the end.

Comment: yes, I did just that. In Core 3.1, OnConfiguring cannot be averted, I guess.

Comment: @Junaid No, this definitely works… Please check against the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to verify that you haven’t missed something. Note in particular, that you need the `public SkipQContext(DbContextOptions<SkipQContext> options)` constructor on your context.

Comment: You are right. That error was persistent as I was using the default constructor in SkipQContext. I had created an object in a helper class using it. I removed the constructor and injected the SkipQContext in the helper class. I then got another error because I had registered some repository as a singleton service. SkipQContext was already injected to the repository class and as we know the SkipQContext is registered as scoped with AddDbContext. So I registered that repository with AddScoped as well and all issues are resolved. Thanks, bro!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to instantiate the Configuration as a Singleton, the Default builder of WebHost already inject the configuration in the request , your Startup Class should look like this

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            string conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("NAME OF YOUR CONNECTION STRING IN THE application.json FILE");
            

            services.AddDbContext<CLASSOFURDBCONTEXT>(config =>
            {
                config.UseSqlServer(conn);
            });

        }
    }
```

And your dbcontext should have the following constructor

```cs
        public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
```

Then you only need to call the DbContext in a controller or a service and the DI will do the rest

As per why your IConfiguration throw the null reference exception i can think of 2 possibilities. Either you need to do the other kind instanciation which would be like this

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration,Configuration>();
```

Or maybe it is because you are not using DI into the DbContext itself, you shouldnt need to do the `new YourContextDbContext()`. You should just simply put it in the constructor of the service or controller and it should work "magically" without you actually need to make an instance of it.